# relation "undefined.{table_name}" does not exist - Unit test a NodeJS Serverless application with Mocha and Chai

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, mocha.js, serverless-framework

I am trying write unit test cases for NodeJS Serverless REST API in Mocha and Chai. The API has database calls in it to Postgres database. So I am trying to use the same database (local Postgres database) that I have used to develop the functionality.

In serverless.yml file, environment variable is set like below

```
custom: 
stage: ${opt:stage, qa}
```

and configuration variables are set like below

```
environment: 
STAGE: ${self:custom.stage}
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.stage}
    DB_USERNAME: ${self:custom.secrets.username}
    DB_PASSWORD: ${self:custom.secrets.password}
    DB_HOST: ${file(./env.yml):${self:custom.stage}-db-host}
    DB_NAME: ${file(./env.yml):${self:custom.stage}-db-name}
    DB_PORT: ${file(./env.yml):${self:custom.stage}-db-port}
    DB_SCHEMA: ${file(./env.yml):${self:custom.stage}-db-schema}
```

and in env.yml file I have values setup for environments like below

```
test-db-host: localhost
test-db-name: schumacher
test-db-port: 5432
test-db-schema: schumacher_user_qa
```

I have changed `NODE_ENV=test` in package.json file under scripts/test in order to run unit test cases. This how it looks in pakage.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha 'tests/*.test.js' --exit" 
}
```

However when I try to run my unit test cases, I am facing '"relation \"undefined.{table_name}\" does not exist' error.

`undefined.{table_name} ---> {schema_name}.{table_name}` - Here the schema value should be taken from environmental variable. But it is `undefined`

Could someone help me how to pass environment values declared in env.yml file to environment variables declared in serverless.yml file to 'test' when running unit test cases? Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is not in the DB connection but rather in the models, you probably declared a model that doesn't have a reflective DB table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mocha doesn't invoke the Serverless Framework, so those variables are never parsed from the ENV file (because the `serverless.yml` file is never read/interpolated).

Instead you should use something like dotenv to parse that file and set variables in your test environment. Or just manually set a few directly on `process.env` in a `beforeAll()` function.